# Prove that there doesn't exist a sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$ of positive integers such that for all i<j, we have $gcd(a_i+j,a_j+i)=1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I guess I can do $gcd(a_i+j, a_j+i) = gcd(a_i+a_j+i+j, a_j+i) = gcd(a_i+a_j+i+j, a_j+i-a_i-j)$. Though, I don't think this leads me anywhere.

I need help figuring out this problem.

Also, would be welcomed any suggestions on how to approach this kind of problems: where I have to prove things about sequences I know nothing about (and in general about problems in number theory involving sequences of numbers).

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1434288p8112441

Comment: I would begin by experimenting how it might happen that $a_i+j$ and $a_j+i$ are never simultaneously even. I haven't checked how far that takes us. But it would allow you to show genuine own effort! Right now, the question is lacking in context, IMO.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR for the resource.

Comment: And thanks @JykriLahtonen for the suggestion. I will try to use them and make some progress.

Comment: @MartinR I know, the question doesn't seem too smart, but how where you able to find this discussion? Cause I don't seem to be able to find it by google search neither using the condition nor the name of the problem.

Comment: @anie: I found it [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd(a_i%2Bj%2Ca_j%2Bi)%3D1%24).  See also [How to search with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks!